# Problems In Doing MySQL Row-Based Replication By Myself

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, replication

I am trying using [MySQL Replication Listener Library](https://launchpad.net/mysql-replication-listener) to do data replication between HostA and HostB.

The replication is based on row-based other than statements. I know there is such built-in feature in MySQL itself, but I want to do it myself --- Reading all row changes from HostA's bin log and applying all these changes to HostB.

The issue I am encountering is, I am not able to disable triggers temporarily, which will cause the data to be out of sync.

Take an example, suppose the database to be synchronized is **TestSyncDB**, and there are two tables in it which are Data and DataOp. The Data table has a trigger with it and once a record is inserted into this table, the trigger will generate a new record to the DataOp.

Now a new record is inserted into HostA.TestSyncDB.Data, since there is a trigger, so there will actually be two records added to the database, and the Replication Listener Library will return to me two queries, something like:

1. insert into HostA.TestSyncDB.Data   values (...)
2. insert into HostA.TestSyncDB.DataOp values (...)  // by trigger

The problem is if I replay these two queries to **HostB**, there will be **three** new records added to tables in **HostA.TestSyncDB**, because of the triggers. Then data is never right ever after.

So how to solve this? Is is possible to disable triggers temporarily? If not, how to do it correctly like what MySQL Replication does?

Answer (score 3):

In mysql replication when you created trigger on master, it will be created on slave. So if you wants different trigger on slave, you can edit that trigger or drop if you don't want.
For the relication format if your master's binlog `binlog_format = ROW`, it will copy as master done, its not fit for triggers if slave wants different trigger action then master as your situation. In this situation binlog required statement based `binlog_format = STATEMENT`. So is it possible in mysql to switch b/w these two as need.

So key point here is You need `binlog_format = MIXED`. It is smart enough to decide when to use `STATEMENT` based and when to used `ROW` based. It will treate as `STATEMENT BASED` for this situation. Other wise it will work as `ROW BASED`.

You can read here more- 
[replication format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-formats.html) and [Advantages and Disadvantages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-sbr-rbr.html)